# HTML Tidy stripping space at the start

Tags: html, tidy, htmltidy

File.html

```
word<i><span> <span>ratti</span></span></i>
```

Command

```
$ tidy File.html
```

Output

```
word<i>ratti</i>
```

Desired output

```
word<i> ratti</i>
```

Where's the space?

Log

> ```
> line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
> line 1 column 1 - Warning: plain text isn't allowed in <head> elements
> line 1 column 8 - Warning: <span> is probably intended as </span>
> line 1 column 5 - Warning: replacing unexpected span by </span>
> line 1 column 33 - Warning: discarding unexpected </span>
> line 1 column 40 - Warning: discarding unexpected </i>
> line 1 column 1 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
> line 1 column 8 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
> Info: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Transitional
> 8 warnings, 0 errors were found!
>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta name="generator" content=
> "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 1st November 2003), see www.w3.org">
> <title></title>
> </head>
> <body>
> word<i>ratti</i>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Seems to be discarded by tidy, did you try  unbreakable space &nbsp; ?

Comment: I can't do anything with the HTML, it's just a sample of 10K+ lines' file, and there are thousands of such files, I can't edit their HTML. There should be an option in `tidy` to preserve spaces in such case. BTW to answer your question, yes it does work fine with &nbsp;

Comment: You can try this option --add-xml-space yes

Comment: Doesn't help, same result. Moreover that works only for `PRE`, `STYLE` and `SCRIPT` + is used only `when generating XML`. Says the [documentation](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/quickref.html#add-xml-space).

Comment: Also see [Ubuntu Issue 1660537](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1660537): *HTML Tidy is dooing a poor job; please update to newer HTML Tidy*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have been solved in newer versions. I was using the version from 2003. I just [updated tidy on my machine](http://www.linuxstall.com/install-html-tidy-linux/) with 2009'th version and with that the output is like below.

```
content: word<i><span> <span>ratti</span></span></i>
command: tidy file.html
output: word <i><span><span>ratti</span></span></i>
```

So it is preserving space now, however it does not delete the `span` tag, anyway this looks like a proper answer to the question.